# Developer Story Privacy Confusion

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Obviously, there are a few similar questions here that pertain to this subject but I have not found something that answers my question specifically.

Essentially, I don't want my developer story public. I change it to private but then I notice in "Developer Story Preference"

> Even if you hide the tab, you will be visible to employers if you have expressed interest in being contacted.

The link in the quote takes me to the first section of the `Job Match Preferences` page which says

> Shown only to employers if you have expressed interest in being contacted.

Is this set by my job search status, i.e. "Actively looking", "Not Interested", or am I supposed to manually express interest to employers that SO matches me with?

Comment: I asked the same question a long time ago and was met with outright derision and snarkiness.  The answer was that your profile is private, but apparently it has changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Making your Developer Story private means it's only visible to you, unless you've also set your Job search status to be 'Actively looking' or 'I'm open, but not actively looking'.  Actively looking will get your Developer Story in front of the most employers and will get you the most job matches.  The 'I'm open..' option means that you can pop up in searches by employers.

If you set your Developer Story to private, and you also set your Job search status to 'Not interested' you will be completely invisible to employers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: So does that mean there is no way to turn off the Developer Story completely and have only the classic resume view shown to employers? That *sounds* like what you're saying, but that isn't how I interpreted the situation at the initial launch of Developer Story. The UX here (knowing what you're actually getting) has not been fantastic.

Comment: @CodyGray Both the developer story and a traditional (timeline) view are available for employers.

Comment: That's too bad. Why isn't there a way to opt out of the Developer Story view altogether? Is that something that would ever be considered, or is this just one of those cases where it's "better" so we are forced to use it?

Comment: I don't want potential employers viewing my stackechange activity. I wish there was a way to post my resume while making my SE activities private.  I've asked this question in the past and to my dismay, I was accused of being paranoid and unreasonable.  It terrifies me that SE community doesn't quite grasp the concept of privacy.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I agree. Plus, if an employer is familiar with SO and has a lot of rep and sees a low rep amount you may not even be considered.

Comment: Exactly!  If you actually spend most of your time programming instead of hanging out in SO, it will count against you.  Some employers are even looking at GitHub accounts and open source projects you're involved in. If whiteboard interviews aren't bad enough, some of them, like FaceBook, use programming contests, which is tantamount to work on spec. Developers need to push back at this abuse.  No other profession deals with this kind of nonsense.  Would Doctors, lawyers allow you to test them before hiring them?