# Private Developer Story tab and expressed interest understanding

Tags: support, status-completed, developer-story

This question was [asked before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354013/developer-story-privacy-confusion), but the answer doesn't explain how all other filters affect the privacy.

Apart from *Job Search status* there are a few other fields and it's completely uncertain for me how they affect visibility of a private Developer story:

- Is a Developer Story visible to **any** employer if status is `Actively Looking` or `Open`? (but depending on other filters this appears more often in their search)

If answer is No:

- Does *Match preference* have any effect on visibility? Do only
  employers from *Job Recommendation* row in my profile can see my
  Developer Story in search?
- Do employers whose jobs were marked by the "Express Interest" button can 
  see a *private Developer Story*?

Sorry if the question is too vague, but I couldn't find comprehensive answer to these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our employer product (Stack Overflow Talent) has two components that deal with candidates.

First we have job listings. These accept applications and interest from candidates. Either of those can use your Developer Story to produce a CV (resumé) for the job. In addition the matching algorithm used in the search engine consumes the job matching preferences you specify in your profile to weight jobs according to your preferences. Recommended jobs in Developer Story is simply showing the jobs we think are most appropriate for you from search based upon your preferences.

Our second product is candidate search which allows employers to search for candidates that meet their search criteria. To be eligible for candidate search you need to have a completed a certain amount of your Developer Story and set your search status to either ‘Actively Looking’ or ‘Open’. Employers that find your profile can see all details on it even if your Developer Story is not publically visible. We also expose *some* of your job matching preferences to employers to help them understand a bit more about you (e.g. seniority, liked tags, etc. But **never** salary expectations). Candidate search also uses those same aspects of your job preferences for filtering or weighting based upon the employer’s search criteria.

Hope that clears things up a little

Comment: Thanks! So privacy doesn't affect visibility of a developer story at all. The description looks misleading then - "even if you hide the tab, you will be visible to employers *if you have expressed interest* in being contacted.

Comment: By "at all" I meant for employers

Comment: Privacy does affect visibility of your story: to everybody that views your profile on Stack Overflow. It does not affect visibility of your Developer Story to employers that paid to use the candidate search product *if* you set you search status to ‘Active Looking’ or ‘Open’

Comment: Visibility to employers in this case means as a result of you appearing in a search that they have performed