# Would it be possible to dismiss job ads from SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I fully understand paid ads are a great income source for SO however seeing the same ads over and over again makes me less likely to pay attention to other ads displaying on the site.

I'd like to think a customisable ads section would greatly benefit user experience where users can choose to see ads for jobs in technologies they are interested in?

For instance I am not interested in Ember.js jobs however this particular ad keeps popping up every time:

[image]

Would it be possible to look into this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You haven't given us much information about yourself, so most of what we show in ads is implied based upon questions you visit. You can give us further information, including what tags you don't want to see by filling in your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).

Comment: Side question: are job preferences public? That is, can anyone see what I set there?

Comment: @LuisMendo I looked at your profile and couldn't find any mention of job preferences

Comment: @LuisMendo no, they are not public. See this post for some details on how they're used: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378897/private-developer-story-tab-and-expressed-interest-understanding/378914#378914